# mysql 1054 error "unknown column" in "on clause"... but the column IS there

Tags: mysql

OK, I'm pulling my hair out on this one.  I've simplified my select statement down a bit on this:

```
SELECT xmatterspagetask.id pagetaskid, xmpurpose.purposetext
FROM xmatterspagetask
LEFT OUTER JOIN xmpurpose on (xmatterspagetask.purpose_id = xmpurpose.id)
```

> #1054 - Unknown column 'xmpurpose.id' in 'on clause'

The xmpurpose table does exist.  It only has two columns, id and purposetext.  It's intended to be a reference table.

I have other very similar two-column reference tables in the full-blown version of this query.   Doing LEFT OUTER JOINs to them works just fine.   Can't figure out why I'm blowing-up on this one.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: You may have over simplified; barring server issues, that looks fine. Have you verified the simpler one has the same issue?

Comment: can you paste the output of "SHOW CREATE TABLE xmpurpose" ?

Comment: 1). Post your table structure and sample data as well. 2) when you say you "simplified my select statement", you may have "simplified" out some important details. Post the whole query.

Comment: Create table (OP did write that the column exists) and sample data are irrelevant. But the original query would be useful.

Comment: @Shadow `SHOW CREATE TABLE` may not be irrelevant if OP is accidentally running a query on a connection to a different (test vs production) server than he is "looking" at; it's not that uncommon around here.

Comment: @Uueerdo I disagree. Ask the OP to check if the code connected to the right database. But you do not need to see the create table. If you simply ask for create table, then the OP will give you the create table of the table he expect to see, which has the field.

Comment: SHOW CREATE TABLE could show you a non-break space char inserted inside a fieldname because of backticks surrounding every ``fieldname`` but you can't be very sure with DESC TABLE default output.

Comment: It could also be a problem with an invalid character in the query, like using a greek "o" (omicron) instead of a latin "o" in the request, both are displayed  the same in many fonts, and yes I've already seen this problem.

Comment: Yes, the simplified one fails too.   

I do see something weird when I dump out the create:

--
-- Table structure for table `xmpurpose`
--

CREATE TABLE `xmpurpose` (
  `â¯id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `purposetext` varchar(20) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


This database was originally created using a wizard from MySQL Workbench 6.3... something I hadn't done before.  Not quite sure how that funky character got in there!   But looks like that must be the problem.

Comment: That was it!  I edited / updated the column name (using phpmyadmin).  The simple query works now.